# Add Fields While Importing TXT to Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to add 3 additional fields with data on them to a .txt file during the import process. But I don't know how to do this. One of those fields would contain the date introduced in the `Combo5` combobox.  The other two, one would contain "Checked" and the other "ArticleN5".

Can anyone provide any instructions on how this can be achieved?

Thank you all in advance,
Hope you're all safe.

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()  

Dim Dates As String  
Dim Path As String  

Dates = Format(Me.Combo5, "yymmdd")  
Path = "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\CGD\20200117\UCP" & Dates & "A_CGD.txt"

DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "UCPYYMMDDA_CGD_SPECS", "teste", PATH, True

End Sub
```

Comment: You could use `TransferText` to import the file into a temporary table and then insert into the main table with something like `INSERT INTO main_table (col_1, col_2, … , date_introduced) SELECT col_1, col_2, … , '210303' AS date_introduced FROM temp_table`

Comment: or, if `main_table` doesn't exist yet you could do `SELECT col_1, col_2, … , '210303' AS date_introduced INTO main_table FROM temp_table`

Answer (score 1):

Do the fields have to be added to the TXT file itself, or to the table where the file is imported to?  If you just need to add the info to the fields in the table, you could open the table as a recordset after the TXT is imported and add the additional data.

Example:

```
Dim rsData as DAO.Recordset
Set rsData = currentDB.openrecordset("TableName", dbtable)
rsData.Movefirst
Do While not rsdata.eof
with rsdata
  .edit
  .field("FieldName") = "Checked"
  .field("FieldName") = comboboxvalue
  .field("FieldName") = value
  .update
end with
rsData.MoveNext

rsdata.close
```

This should get you close

Comment: thanks for the quick reply :)  I need to add these fields to the table where the file is imported. Can you explain to me how this can be done?

Comment: apparently there is something missing. I get a loop error. Even thought I did an `Exit do` any advise?

Comment: ooops. put 'Loop' underneath rsData.MoveNext.  Sorry about that.